# In this question, which one is known as function declaration (prototype)?

Tags: c, function, prototype

```
void add (int a, int b)
{
  int c= a+b;
  printf("the value of c is %d",c);
}

void main()
{    
  int x,y;
  printf("Enter two numbers: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
  add (x,y);
}
```

I understand what function deceleration or prototype is...But which
line of code in this program is considered to be a function prototype
.....Or there isn't any function prototype in this program???

Comment: THANKS @tadman BUT I UNDERSTAND THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN FUNCTION DEFINITION AND PROTOTYPE ...MY QUESTION IS WHICH LINE IN THIS PROGRAM IS CONSIDERED TO BE THE FUNCTION DECLARATION OR PROTOTYPE?

Comment: There is no prototype or declaration in the code you've posted, only a definition.

Comment: Look, don't ALL CAPS me like that. It's yelling and it's ridiculous.

Comment: A definition counts as a declaration, but not vice-versa.

Comment: @tadman haha sorry for the caps man

Comment: function prototype is not at all the same as function declaration

Comment: `void add (int a, int b)` is a prototype, and `void main()` is not.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you did not write the declaration of function at all.

By the way `void main()` is not correct, always use `int main()`

```
// function declaration
void add (int a, int b);

// function definition
void add (int a, int b)
{
   int c= a+b;
   printf("the value of c is %d",c);
}

void main()
{

    int x,y;
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    // function call
    add (x,y);
}
```

Comment: I DON'T THINK THAT IT IS NECESSARY TO WRITE FUNCTION PROTOTYPE IN THE TOP AFTER YOU WRITE THE DEFINITION OF THE FUNCTION ABOVE THE MAIN FUNCTION IN C...

Comment: It isn't necessary, but it is how you titled your question so it seems perfectly valid to add it, even though it is not needed in this case, because you asked about it. You might ease off on the caps, it doesn't help.

Comment: Function definitions are declarations too.